Hahn-Banach Theorem First Geometric Form Exercise
I'm currently studying Functional Analysis, and I'm struggling with the reciprocal part of an exercise:
Let $E$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}, A \subset E $ an open and convex set such that $0 \in A$, and $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ a linear functional. Define $Y = f^{-1}(1)$. Show that $f(x) \leq p_A(x)$ for all $x\in E$ if and only if $A \cap Y = \emptyset$, where $p_A$ denotes the Minkowski functional associated with $A$.
The first implication is straightforward: suppose $ A \cap Y \ne \emptyset $. Then, there exists $x_0 \in A \cap Y$, so $ f(x_0) = 1 $ and $p_A(x_0) < 1$, since $A = \{ x \in E \mid p_A(x) < 1 \}$. Thus, $1 = f(x_0) \leq p_A(x_0) < 1$, which is a contradiction.
For the reciprocal, one can show that $Y$ is convex. Assuming $A \cap Y = \emptyset$, by the Hahn-Banach Theorem (First Geometric Form), there exists $\tilde{f} \in E'$ and $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $\tilde{f}(x) < a \leq \tilde{f}(y)$ for all $ x \in A $ and $ y \in Y $. From here, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Since $\tilde{f}(x) <  \tilde{f}(y)$ for all $x \in A, y \in Y$ and we know that $0\in A$, we know that $\tilde{f}(y) > 0$. Since $Y$ is affine, $\tilde{f}$ must be constant on $Y$ (otherwise $\tilde{f}(Y)$ would be $\mathbb{R}$), and so we have $\ker \tilde{f} = \ker f$ and so $\tilde{f} = \lambda f$ for some $\lambda > 0$ (since $\tilde{f}(y) >0$ for $y \in Y$).
Hence $f(x) < f(y)$ for all $x \in A, y \in Y$ (and $f(y)=1$ by definition of $Y$). If $f(x) \le 0$ then we automatically have $f(x) \le p_A(x)$, so we can assume that $f(x)>0$. For $r>0$, let $y(r) = {1 \over r}x$, and note that $f(y(r)) = {1 \over r} f(x)$.
Note that if $y(r) \in A$ (equivalently, $x \in rA$) we have $f(y(r)) = {1 \over r} f(x) \le 1$, or $f(x) \le r$. Since $p_A(x) = \inf \{ r >0 | x \in rA \}$, we see that $f(x) \le p_A(x)$.
